# unable to boot windows after installing ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu

I have a new HP laptop. I have deployed windows 8.1 & ubuntu 15.  Recently I removed ubuntu 15 and deployed ubuntu 10.04.  Installation have been completed successfully.  But after restarting the system I can not boot either windows or ubuntu.  It is showing GNU GRUB version 2.02~beta2-29
Minimal BASH-l ine.

Answer (score 0):

You should just boot into the system from live CD /USB , write/install and update grub on all the hard drives or just on the drive where both windows and Ubuntu reside.

**Procedure:**

Boot to a live try Ubuntu session, then run the following at a terminal prompt:

```
 a) sudo mount /dev/sdaX /mnt # Make "sdaX" the partition that has Ubuntu install (i.e. /dev/sda2)
 b) for i in /sys /proc /run /dev; do sudo mount --bind "$i" "/mnt/$i"; done
 c) sudo chroot /mnt
 d) update-grub
 e) if no errors skip this "e" section
    grub-install /dev/sdX (sdX is the hard drive that has linux installed  (i.e. /dev/sda)
 update-grub 5) Reboot the system
```

**Find Linux Installation**

In a terminal, run the command `df -h` and look at the output. The column headed "Mounted On" will have a "/" against the partition that holds your root filesystem. This is where your system is installed.

If there is some logical volume displayed then use `lvdisplay`  , this will show the volume group in which that logical volume reside , then use `pvdisplay` to find out on which drive the volume group reside

Comment: thank you for your information Ijaz Khan,  may I know how to find out in which drive/partition ubuntu is installed.  Is there any command to find it out.  Kindly give me your contact number if u don't mind

Comment: Welcome , Answer updated